# How can Perl's XSUB die?

Tags: perl, xs, perl-xs

I have written a Perl XS wrapper for a C library consisting of about ~80
functions. Right now my general strategy is to substitute the error from a C
function with `PL_sv_undef` and the calling Perl code has to check explicitly
whether the return is not `undef`. (For some C functions it is more complicated
as I convert their output into a `HV`/`AV` and use empty list to report the error.)

Now as I moved to writing bigger Perl scripts using that library, I want to
simplify the error handling and use e.g. the usual `eval {}`/`die` exception-like
mechanism to handle errors.

At the moment a simple XSUB in my XS look like that:

```
SV *
simple_function( param1, param2 = 0, param3 = 0)
        int             param1
        int             param2
        int             param3
        CODE:
                int rc;
                rc = simple_function( param1, param2, param3 );
                RETVAL = (rc == 0) ? &PL_sv_yes : &PL_sv_undef;
        OUTPUT:
                RETVAL
```

I have seen that some modules have global flag like "RaiseError" to `die` on
errors but failed to find any example I can borrow from. The few modules I have
found handle the "RaiseError" flag inside the `.pm`, not inside the `.xs`, and
thus allowed to use the Perl's `die`. In my case that is rather hard to
implement inside the `.pm` as many functions require special error checks. That
would also lead to code duplication as the checks are already present inside the XS.

I found nothing relevant in the [`perlxs`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html)/[`perlguts`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html) documentation. In particular, I have seen calls to `Perl_croak()` in the `.c` generated from my `.xs`, but failed to locate any documentation for the function.

What is the XS' analog of the Perl's `die`? Or how else can the XSUB report to Perl
run-time that the function has failed and there is no RETVAL to return? How to properly set the `$@`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl_croak() is documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#Warning-and-Dieing) on the `perlapi` man page. As the example on that page shows, you can either pass it a message string, or you can manually set $@ to an exception object and pass NULL.

Comment: Only one question. Why *dieing* and not *dying*? Or was it another Larry's wit?

Comment: No, [Zefram](http://search.cpan.org/~zefram)'s. It's [hackish](http://catb.org/jargon/html/writing-style.html) usage because it derives from the keyword `die`.